# how to implement partial word match for result using elastic search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

i am new to elastic search and want to implement partial word match in my application don't know how to implement please suggest me my code is as follows:

article.rb file

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
        include Tire::Model::Search
      include Tire::Model::Callbacks


      settings analysis: {
        filter: {
          ngram_filter: { type: "nGram", min_gram: 2, max_gram: 12 }
        },
        analyzer: {
          partial_analyzer: {
            type: "snowball",
            tokenizer: "standard",
            filter: ["standard", "lowercase", "ngram_filter"]
          }
        }
      } do
        mapping do
          indexes :title, index_filter: "ngram_filter"
          indexes :body, index_analyzer: "partial_analyzer"
          indexes :id
        end
      end
      def self.search(params)
        tire.search() do
          query { string params[:query]} if params[:query].present?
        end
      end
    end

article_controller.rb

    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
      def index
         if params[:query].present?
            @articles = Article.search(params)
            # @articles = Article.where(title: params["query"])
         else
            @articles = Article.all
         end

         respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :layout => false }
            format.html 

         end

      end
    end
```

i also don't have much knowledge about mapping r indexing so please suggest me solution, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform partial search by passing asterisk(*) in your search box like:

> *search_term

and by default you want it in your search method just append it like

```
def self.search(params)
        tire.search() do
          query { string "*#{params[:query]}*" } if params[:query].present?
        end
end
```

Comment: thanx dear i had implemented this already can you tell me how to index data whenever new data added to article table becoze every time i am running command  rake environment tire:import CLASS=Content FORCE=true. is there any other method to implement this?

Comment: There is a concept of "mapping" in elastic search  make use of it.  like: mapping do indexes :id, type: 'integer'  indexes :title indexes :body end  for id i defined as integer because by default it take as string.

Comment: bro i have used mapping u can see above in articles.rb even its not working i always have to run this command "rake environment tire:import CLASS=Content FORCE=true. "

Comment: For each new record no need of re-indexing each time once if you do for new table its enough, Can you post the error.

Comment: there is no error but whenever i search the article which is newly added it doesnot search but after running command  rake environment tire:import CLASS=Content FORCE=true its working fine.

Comment: bro thanx for your support i want to implement full text based search on a blog application can you suggest me from where i can learn coz i m still confused about indexing

Comment: Check this you will get an idea i have implemented for Blog itself.   https://github.com/gouravnaik/Search-Engine  It consist 3 type of search Ransack, Sunspot and Elastic check the Read_Me.

Comment: bro can u tell me i want to customize my search then how can i customise beacuse using query { string "*#{params[:query]}*" } matches each word i need some more customization.

Comment: Which kind of customization you need tell me, I can help

Comment: i want customization like after two words type it should match result from starting sentance.

Answer (score 0):

You need write like this and make sure fix fuzziness of searching and which column use for searching like title.

```
@term = params[:keyword].to_s
@results =  JobSubcategory.search({#size: 20 ,
                                     query: {
                                         multi_match:{
                                                        query: @term,
                                                        fields: [ "title"],
                                                        fuzziness: 2
                                                     }
                                                    }}).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page])
```